# Kendo Grid Filter Suggestion List Html Encoded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

Is there a way that we can html decode the selection list of the kendo grid filter? Please see my sample output. I want to output a not encoded value. By the way the "&#252;" value in the picture corresponds to 'ü'. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, you just need to declare a template in Filter Cell.

Code in the backend razor:

```
.Filterable(f => f
    .Cell( c => c.Template("testFilterTemplate")
)
```

Code in JS:

```
testfilterTemplate: function testfilterTemplate(container) {
    container.element.kendoAutoComplete({
        filter: 'contains',
        dataSource: container.dataSource,
        dataTextField: 'testfield',
        valuePrimitive: true,
        template: function kendoAutoCompleteTemplate(data) {
            return data.testfield ? htmlDecode(data.testfield) : '';
        },
        select: function kendoAutoCompleteSelect(e) {
            var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
            dataItem.testfield = htmlDecode(dataItem.testfield);
        }
    });
```